# Display no results when table empty in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have a table of rows that display contact information. I'd like to have it render a messasge of "No contacts" when the `listItems` array is 0. I tried creating a `const noEntries` variable and setting it with the array to 0, and using {noEntries No entries}, but this is throwing an error.

```
class ContactList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.createContact = this.createContact.bind(this);
  }

  delete(key) {
    this.props.delete(key);
  }

  createContact(item) {
    return  <tr key={item.key}>
              <td>{item.firstname}</td>
              <td>{item.lastname}</td>
              <td>{item.phone}</td>
              <td><i className="fas fa-trash-alt" onClick={() => { if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ' + item.firstname + ' ' + item.lastname + ' from your contacts?')) this.delete(item.key)}}></i></td>
            </tr>
  }

  render() {
    const contactEntries = this.props.entries;
    const listItems = contactEntries.map(this.createContact);
    return (
      <table className="mui-table mui-table--bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {listItems}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
};

export default ContactList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `render()` do like this:

```
render() {
    const contactEntries = this.props.entries;
    const listItems = contactEntries.map(this.createContact);
    return (
      contactEntries.length > 0?
      <table className="mui-table mui-table--bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {listItems}
        </tbody>
      </table>:<span>No results</span>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

check the number of records in `contactEntries` using ternary operator if `length ==0` then `return` no data component else `return rows`

```
        const listItems = contactEntries && contactEntries.length >0 
                        ?  contactEntries.map(this.createContact) 
               : <tr key={item.key}>
                  <td rowspan="3">No data</td
                </tr>
```

Comment: Add some explanation to it.